# while loop working differently in different projects, but the same code structure?

Tags: java, while-loop

I've written this code:

```
while (choice > 2 && count <= 2) {
    System.out.println("The number you have typed is invalid. Please try again.");
    choice = s.nextInt();
    count++;
}

if (choice == 1 && count <= 2) {
    System.out.println("You have chosen teacher's information.");
    t.information();
} else if (choice == 2 && count <= 2) {
    System.out.println("You have chosen student's information.");
    st.info();
} else {
    System.out.println("You have been blocked.");
}
```

It works how I intended to, if I try more than 2 times, I'll be blocked, however, in this other project:

```
while (!rusern.equalsIgnoreCase(username) || !rpass.equals(password) && attempts <= 2) {
    System.out.println("Login error. Your username is: " + rusern.equalsIgnoreCase(username) + " ,and password is: " + rpass.equals(password) + "\nPlease try again.");
    System.out.println("Please enter your username:");
    rusern = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter your password:");
    rpass = s.nextLine();
    attempts++;
    //here i have to use break;
}

if (rusern.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && rpass.equals(password) && attempts <= 2) {
    System.out.println("You have succesfully logged in! Please continue: ");
} else {
    System.out.println("You have been blocked.");
}
```

I have to use break; in the while loop, where I mentioned in the comment, because unless I used the break, it would show the questions over and over if I didn't answer correctly, without stopping, and when I finally answered right, it would have me blocked. So my question is, why wouldn't it work without the break like in the first project?
Both variables, the 'attempts' and 'count' and initialized the same, = 0.

Comment: Your logic for checking if the username and password are correct should be inside the while method. Inside the `if` statements you would put a `break;` to leave the loop once the user has either entered correct credentials or `attempts` has exceeded 2.

Comment: And since you will be `break`ing out of the loop manually your `while` loop's condition can also just be `while (attempts <= 2) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a || b && c` means `a || (b && c)` while I believe you intended it to mean `(a || b) && c`.

See [Java operator precedence table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html): `||` and `&&` don't have equal precedence.

So your loop should be:

```
while ((!rusern.equalsIgnoreCase(username) || !rpass.equals(password)) && attempts <= 2) {
```

Comment: @alison If an answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it. (The green check mark next to the votes on the answer) It'll give both you and the person who answered reputation points and it will indicate that the answer is correct

Comment: @GBlodgett oh, okay, I'm new to stackoverflow, so I didn't know I should've done that. Thank you.

Comment: @alison No worries! Welcome to stack overflow!